# How Do I Count Up By Two In PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop, numbers, echo

So I'm trying to make it so the computer counts up to ten by two and making a new line each time. When I tested this my entire computer crashed. What's wrong with it?

```
 <?php
$test = 0;
while ($test < 10) {
    $test + 2;
    echo $test . "/n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$test + 2;
```

to:

```
$test += 2;
```

Currently, `$test` is always `0` in your code, since you are not assigning a new value to it, hence the infinite loop.

Additionally, you would also want to change:

```
echo $test . "/n";
```

to:

```
echo $test . "\n";
```

Since you need to use a backslash to indicate a new line character.

**N.B.** In PHP you can also use the `PHP_EOL` constant to indicate the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

Here you just sum `$test` with 2 but did not assign it back to `$test`
$test + 2;

Trying replace it by $test += 2;

Another point is `/n` is not "making a new line" as you expected, change it to `\n` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `while` statement, this is a good case to use `for` instead.

```
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i += 2)
{
    echo $i . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Usually `while` is used to evaluate something every loop, some variable that can change inside the `while`, like a bool variable or an "infinite" loop until break.
When you have a already defined number of loops, `for` is usually a better approach.